# Error in webscraping loop Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this webiste: https://knowyourcity.info/explore-our-data/

I have put all of the URLs of each data page into an object called urllist and have written this loop:

```
name = []
year = []
country = []
population = []
taps = []
toiletsToPerson = []

from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for u in urllist:
    response = get(u)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for u in urllist:
    response = get(u)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    headers_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'settlement-base-status section text-center')
    names = headers_containers.h2.text
    name.append(names)
    year_established = headers_containers.h3.text
    year.append(year_established)
    headers1_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-xs-12 text-center')
    countries = headers1_containers.h4.a.text
    country.append(countries)
    headers2_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'bold-it', id = "population")
    populations = headers2_containers.text
    population.append(populations)
    headers3_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ ='bold-it', id='sharedTaps')
    tap = headers3_containers.text
    taps.append(tap)
    headers4_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'bold-it')
    toiletSeat_toPerson = headers4_containers[7].text
    toiletsToPerson.append(toiletSeat_toPerson)
```

When I used these commands for a single URL it did work but when I try to run this I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-472-0f7d711bfd3f>", line 5, in <module>
    names = headers_containers.h2.text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'h2'
```

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

Your urllist is not defined in your given code, are you sure this is the right one?
Also you can use try + except to handle parsing errors

```
try:
    headers_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'settlement-base-status section text-center')
    names = headers_containers.h2.text
    name.append(names)
except:
    continue
```

Comment: This is returning invalid syntax! and i've defined the URL in urllist before does that work or does it have to be in the loop?